# What should I do when a bunch of machines keep trying to SSH into mine?

Tags: ssh, security, bots, attack-vector

For the past few hours, a bunch of machines from China (well, supposedly) have been trying to SSH into my machine as root, and failing. Some (all?) of their IPs are:

```
218.65.30.53
221.194.47.221
115.238.245.2
115.238.245.4
221.194.47.239
```

I've used a web-based whois to check on them, and have wrote to the abuse report addresses. What are things should I do? On my machine and in general?

Comment: I assume you cannot just simply disable SSH?  I also assume you have used the appropriate steps to block those ip addresses from accessing your server.  If you are not using key authentication it's time to switch.

Comment: Don't run your ssh server on a standard port number. Disable user/password logins in favour of using a private key. Don't leave your ssh server accessible via the internet.

Comment: @Ramhound: Can't disable SSH - I need to use it. But I'll think about disabling password-based login.

Comment: @Mokubai:  I'm thinking about moving it to another port. It's a hassle though :-(

Comment: If you're using pubkey auth, simply ignore them - the only damage they could possibly do is increase your log size.

Comment: Consider fail2ban in the immediate term, changing your port in the short term, and switching over to keys in the longer term.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Could you expand this comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you can (and arguably should) do.

1. Implement a VPN, and only allow access across the VPN.  This will decrease the attack surface greatly.
2. Use Fail2Ban or equivalent to frustrate brute force attacks.
3. Require logons use public/private key authentication.
4. Add a list of allowed users by adding an AllowUsers directive to /etc/ssh/sshd_config with a list of allowed users (and associated IP addresses)
5. Disable root logins (or if required, strictly limit to particular static IP addresses as per 4 above)

Comment: What do you mean by "implement a VPN"? Also - root login is disabled by default IIANM. Also, could you explain what Fail2Ban is?

Comment: If you run OpenVPN on the server (or associated router) and then connect to the VPN remotely, you can SSH in over that. You can assign an IP address and limit SSH to that.  Fail2Ban is software which monitors logs and can, for example, block access from an associated IP for a certain time for an associated IP. This can frustrate DI